# Tuples vs NSDictionary when returning multiple value, seem same?

Tags: objective-c, swift, tuples, nsdictionary

I learned about `tuple` and one benefit mentioned is

> - Tuple can contain different values with different datatype, dictionary can contain only on datatype value at a time

`ex: let nameAndAge = (name:"Jon", age:10)`

but dictionary can also return multiple data types (which are non primitive) if I am correct.

```
NSDictionary *dict= @{@"name":@"jon",@"age":[NSNumber numberWithLongLong: age],@"array":[NSArray new]} ... etc;
```

These are different datatypes passed in dictionary, am I missing something? thanks.

Comment: the point if for the code witch will get the data. If you returns a dict, no one knows for sure what's in. with a tuple, you know exactly the content of the return

Comment: when we are talking about tuples, we are using Swift. NSDictionary is legacy type used in Objective C and ported to Swift. In swift, we have Dictionary and the only way to have multiple type is to use AnyObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each variable in `Swift` has a specific type, be it `tuple` or `dictionary`.

In the following `tuple`:

```
let nameAndAge = (name:"Jon", age:10)
```

`nameAndAge` is of type `(String, Int)`

In `dictionary`, the `type` is referred by the values it contains,

```
let dict = ["One": 1, 1: "One"]
```

`dict` is of type `[AnyHashable:Any]`

In

```
NSDictionary *dict= @{@"name":@"jon",@"age":[NSNumber numberWithLongLong: age],@"array":[NSArray new]} ... etc;
```

Although, it is in `Objective-C`, in `Swift` it will have a type of `[String:Any]`

i.e. `let dict = ["name":"jon", "age":10, "array":[String]]`

A `dictionary` key-value pair types are the one that satisfies all the elements it contains, i.e. top-most superclass.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift:

**Tuple**

> Tuples group multiple values into a single compound value. The values within a tuple can be of any type and don’t have to be of the same type as each other.

**Dictionary**

> A dictionary stores associations between keys of the same type and values of the same type in a collection with no defined ordering. Each value is associated with a unique key, which acts as an identifier for that value within the dictionary.

Furthermore, for a dictionary you can declare it with the type `Any` if you want to have multiple types.

For example:

`var dictionary = Dictionary<String, Any>()`

For more info:

[Tuple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

[Dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)